# Mapping a Transient Property to an Alias - Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Is it possible in Spring JPA to map a Transient property of an Object to an alias like so?

Native Query

```
SELECT *, 1 AS liked FROM User WHERE user_id = 123 // + logic to determine if liked
```

Class

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name = "displayName")
    private String displayName;

    @Transient
    private int liked; // not tied to any column

}
```

I've tried to implement this but `liked` always returns 0 where it should be 1 (and null if I defined the field as an Object type)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You may few solutions, remap in getter, @PostLoad etc, but generally seems building on previous design error. JPA entity is object expression of database row (very simplification, sorry), should not falsify for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You should use @Formula annotation for the field (see [the example](http://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/formula_hibernate_annotation))

> The @Formula annotation to provide an SQL snippet which Hibernate will execute when it fetches the entity from the database. The return value of the SQL snippet gets mapped to a read-only entity attribute.

Comment: I had no knowledge of this, it sounds exactly like what I'm looking for thank you!

Comment: You won't have any knowledge of it if using standard JPA since it is Hibernate-specific, which the poster failed to disclose